# java.lang.outofmemoryerror bitmap on a fragment pager

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have some memory leak problem I can't find the way to solve. There are many questions in stackoverflow but no one of them was useful for me.

I have an activitiy with a view pager and action bar tabs navigation. In every fragment I load   only one image so that this is sort of a gallery in the end. That works nice.

After some fragment changes, I got this error:

E/AndroidRuntime(19271): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(19271):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)

All I've read is about the need of deallocating images, so I thought something about:

1. Event at "fragment lost focus"
2. Delete all views inside the fragment whose focus has lost

But I can't find any solution like that. Is that the correct way? If so, can you give an example? Or I'm completely wrong and the solution is another way?

This is how I add the images to the fragment:

```
             ImageView img = new ImageView(rootView.getContext());
             img.setVisibility(1);
             img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery_image_1);
             img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
             img.setTag( "gallery_image_1" );
             gallery.addView(img);
```

Thanks to all in advance!

Diego

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you're using [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html), as it's more memory-friendly than `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Second, analyze your application with [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to find what really causes memory leaks. [Here's](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) an excellent post describing how this tool can be used in context of Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed to FragmentStatePagerAdapter but it hasn't helped ( I'd say it works worse now ).  I installed MAT but apart from telling me that byte[] ( which is where bitmap info is stored ) is the class which is filling the memory, I can't move forward to a solution.

Comment: In the end, it seems I found a simple solution here:        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583485/android-outofmemory-drawable  It works perfectly by now to me.