# Android Out of Memory error

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585067/1353517) answer to help solve my out of memory issue. The solution was to move all the drawables to a new drawable folder inside the assets folder and use this function

```
 public static Drawable getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
        return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
    }
```

My question is how do I use this function within my Activity? Is there an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I use this function within my Activity?

Well, as the  function is `public static` simply:

```
 className.getAssetImage(this, yourDrawableName);
```

without creating an `instance` of the class `className (Utils)`

ex:

`Drawable mDrawable = Utils.getAssetImage(this, "my_drawable_image_name");`

where `mDrawable` is the `Drawable` image returned.