# Java Out of Memory Error while loading the UI of an Android Activity

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have been trying to load a very basic activity with on ImageButton, 2 textViews, a textField and an ImageView.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:id="@+id/namescreenactivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Welcome to your Pet House"
    android:id="@+id/Welcome"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Welcome"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Welcome" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Name your pet"
    android:id="@+id/NameLabel"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Welcome" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sun"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Welcome"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:id="@+id/sun" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/camel"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp" />
```

And in MainActivity.java's OnCreate function I am simply calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
However, my application's memory usage graph shows that I am utilizing around 44MB (Although the total size of all my images in the app is less than 1MB and the one used for the ImageButton is 193KB).

I believe that this is the reason my app crashes and throws an Out of Memory error

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 138018828 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 35MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:78)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
at com.example.healthypetdhr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)'
```

Please help me figure out what's wrong and how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please also provide the "@drawable/sun" and "@drawable/camel" images?

Comment: Keep in mind that images are decoded to a bitmap when they are drawn. This is normal but requires much more memory than the file in your APK.

Comment: Don't load the large images directly to imageview, instead use the bitmap options to resize it to the desire size and than set to imageview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may happen when Images are big and when they are placed in drawable(ldpi/mdpi...) folder so android OS tends to resize them according to need, but in your case you said they are very small, still try putting those images inside:

```
res/drawable-nodpi
```

folder as it avoids them from rescaling and to be used as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It might require more memory space after the images are decoded to bitmap, you can use bitmap options, modify the parameters to resize it;

You might want to `clean` and `refresh` your project;

Check the res folder as people said;

Refer this to study more: 
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

It is highly probable that the drawables you are using cause this problem.
You may want to refer to his question
[Android Outofmemory drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583485/android-outofmemory-drawable)

Comment: how should I use the getAssetImage() method mentioned in the answer? can you please guide me?