# Out of memory error while loading one image

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I am getting an OutOfMemmory error while loading an image in an activity.
I have one activity with one image and thats it. I dont understand how one image can cause this error

Log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 144288012 byte allocation with 2126212 free bytes and 92MB until OOM
                                                 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
                                                 at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
                                                 at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:162)
                                                 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                 at in.snipped.snippedsalons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:10)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: What is the size of the image?

Comment: Its about 250kb

Comment: you need to check the size of the drawable you r choosing from resources or gallery.

Comment: Isnt 250kb small?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Outofmemory drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583485/android-outofmemory-drawable)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the missing in manifest application

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Comment: "Do not solve this kind of issue with `android:largeHeap="true"`, that's not a solution".

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution to get rid of this error

1. Compress your image and change the resolution as per your need.
2. Use glide to load image, glide make copy of that image as according to your image view's size

You can try both.

Comment: The image is just 250kb. That isn't that big

Comment: yes that's big , your image size should be 50 to 60 kb approx

Comment: and also this size increase app size which is not best practice

Comment: Yeah but this is the logo and I kinda need it here

Comment: then use glide to do your task